# Not looping through data with ES6 Map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have array that i want to map through the values and i can not get the ES6 map to work correctly. Below is my code.
Thanks for the help.

```
 0: "FOLDER2"
 1: "FOLDER3

renderNames = () => {
  const listItems = this.props.clickedFolderNames
    .map((number, index) => <ListItem key={index} value={number} />);

  return (
    <ul>
      {listItems}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

Comment: what kind of error do you have?

Comment: i am not getting an error it doesnt display anything in the list

Comment: Are you sure clickedFolderNames is an array?

Comment: @GreatKhan2016 can you do a consol.log / debugger after you create listItems?

Comment: (2) ["FOLDER2", "FOLDER3"]
0
:
"FOLDER2"
1
:
"FOLDER3"
length
:
2
__proto__
:
Array(0)

Comment: @GreatKhan2016, so nothing happens, when you call renderNames(); ?

Comment: no it just called map function. i have {this.renderNames()} in my return

Comment: Where exactly did you place this console.log? Maybe your context is wrong due to arrow function? Some kind of pastebin would be more useful

Comment: i place the console.log before the map. i did console.log(this.props.clickedFolderNames)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177569/discussion-between-great-khan-2016-and-justme).

Comment: i got it working. the issue was more to with material ui . i was calling the map function in the wrong place

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your anonymous function block in curly brackets and `return` a value if you are splitting it over multiple lines:

```
.map((number,index) => {
     return (<ListItem key={index}
              value={number} />)
      });
  return (
    <ul>
      {listItems}
    </ul>
  );
}
```